# Выбор ТОЛЬКО папок в JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing

Пытался запретить выбор файлов (можно выбирать только файлы) путем функции JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object src = e.getSource();
    JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
    if(src == parent.jb1) {
        a = jfc.showDialog(null, "Open directory");
        jfc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        if(a == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File file = jfc.getCurrentDirectory();
            str = file.getAbsolutePath();
        }
    }
}
```

Однако попытка не удалась, окно выводит файлы с расширением .jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы просто сказали, что можно выбирать директории. Чтобы отфильтровать директории нужно использовать `setFileFilter`

```
jfc.setFileFilter(new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File f) {
        return f.isDirectory();
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "";
    }
});
```

Если применить к вашему коду, то получиться вот так

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object src = e.getSource();
    JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
    // показывать только директории
    jfc.setFileFilter(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File f) {
            return f.isDirectory();
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {return "";}
    });
    // выбирать только директории
    jfc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    if(src == parent.jb1) {
        a = jfc.showDialog(null, "Open directory");
        if(a == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File file = jfc.getCurrentDirectory();
            str = file.getAbsolutePath();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The method setFileFilter(FileFilter) in the type JFileChooser is not applicable for the arguments (new FileFilter(){})